# How to check that object is a linear subspace of appropriate vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to check that all vectors from $\textbf{R}_n$ which coordinates satisfy an equation $$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n = 1$$ are linear subspace of appropriate vector space.

Is there generic approach for such a problem? I am not sure where and how I should start.

Comment: It is only an *affine* subspace, i.e. a vector subspace which is  *translated*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need is to show that if there exist two set of solutions then their linear combinations is also a solution. Let two sets $(x_n )_{n=1}^N$ and $(y_n )_{n=1}^N$ satisfy the equation, i.e.

$$\sum_{n=1}^N x_n = 1  ; \sum_{n=1}^N y_n = 1. $$

Then if you can find some $\alpha,\beta\in R$ such that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (\alpha x_n+ \beta y_n)= 1 , \exists \alpha , \beta \in R ,$$

you proved that a linear combination of solutions is also solution, and therefore the set of all solutions form a linear subspace.  One can write
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (\alpha x_n+ \beta y_n)=\alpha\sum_{n=1}^N  x_n+\beta \sum_{n=1}^N  y_n= \alpha (1)+\beta (1) = \alpha +\beta = 1, $$

therefore for any two sets of solutions $(x_n)_{n=1}^N ,(y_n)_{n=1}^N$, their linear combination $(\alpha x_n + (1-\alpha) y_n)_{n=1}^N$ is also a solution.

Comment: If the solutions indeed form a linear subspace of some vectorspace then they form a vectorspace themselves hence there must be a neutral element. Which one?

Comment: If the linear subspace is a vector space in its own right then it form a vector subspace. In other words, any linear subspace does not necessarily form a vector space. For example the zero element (additive identity element) may not be in the subspace. The other conditions for being a vector space is that it must be closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition.

Comment: Then what is your definition of [linear subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace)?

Comment: In the answer I told what I meant by linear subspace. But regarding your terminology (that may be standard one), you're right, and my answer is wrong. We call such space, a ''vector subspace'' to emphasize that it is also a vector space.Thanks for your hint.